# What commercial WPF suite is better? Please suggest

Tags: wpf, components, telerik, devexpress

Im working on a middle size project, using WPF. Need DataGrid, suitable for the client: fast, customizable, beautiful. Which component suite do you suggest from your practice?(for example Devexpress's, telerik's, Infragistics's and etc)

Comment: Might as well add Infragistics in there. All those control toolkits are a PITA in one way or another.

Comment: @Stingyjack, thank you..Added and rephrased..

Comment: How about the DataGrid from the WpfToolkit? It's made by Microsoft outside of the normal .NET Framework ship cycle, whatever that means..

Comment: @Wouter it has no filters, grouping and ets + there were some performance issues with its databinding. So now i want to try some commercial ones and see the difference.

Comment: It does support filtering and grouping via ICollectionView. However, this might not be as comfortable as the solutions provided by commercial products. But I still prefer the WPF DataGrid because it sticks to the typical WPF concepts, rather than introducing completely new concepts which restrict you to a certain product. Well, but that is my personal opinion. You better download the trials and test them for your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Telerik data grid in the past and it seemed to have the least hastles for me compared to others I have had a look at.

However I can pretty much put my money on it that someone else would feel that Telerik's control wasn't great and that Infragistics was better etc. - so I suggest that you maybe download the trials and test them for your specific scenario.

Comment: +1 for trying them to see which one suits your scenario best.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try all the demos and see. Tho i want people here to tell specific strengths and weaknesses of the components they have used.

Answer (score 1):

"Fast, customizable, beautiful." - try Xceed's (I work there), there's a no-install XBAP demo. Also supports asynchronous data virtualization and smooth scrolling and other stuff no other datagrid does.

[Xceed DataGrid for WPF main page](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html)

[XBAP demos page](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've been evaluating Xceed for a few weeks now and while it is powerful it's dog slow when placed in a tab control switching between tabs. 30 seconds to open a tab on a large data set. The forum on their website seems to suggest this is a known problem without resolution. Shame as in other aspects it appears to do a good job.